# transitionToRoute().then not resolving

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a case where  `transitionToRoute().then(...)` resolves after transition from one subroute, but not from the other.

Yet I don't see any difference:

Routes:

```
this.resource('departments', {path: '/'}, function() {
    this.resource('department', { path: 'department/:department_id' }, function() {
        this.resource('posts',  { path: '/timeline' }, function(){
            this.resource('post', { path: '/:post_id' });
        });
        ...
```

When I am on the route *'departments.department.posts.index'* I can transitionToRoute from withing my departmentsController and the promise will resolve:

```
this.transitionToRoute('posts.index', department).then(function() {
  callback();
});
```

Yet when I am at a deeper level route: *'departments.department.posts.post'* the then promise is not resolving.

Is there some logic I am missing that makes the callback not resolving?

Answer (score 3):

There is no deeper level route 'departments.department.posts.post' actually. Router's map is almost flat in your case because of missed parent's names in 'children' routes. You can explore that itself: I've prepared an example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/dokuqozivice/1/
It might be the reason of strange behavior that you observe.

General reason for promise's failing is aborting transition in transitioning sequence. There are might be several reasons for that besides one already described. You can turn trace options for deeply debugging:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
    LOG_STACKTRACE_ON_DEPRECATION: true,
    LOG_BINDINGS: true,
    LOG_TRANSITIONS: true, // print all transitionTo information
    LOG_TRANSITIONS_INTERNAL: true,
    LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS: true,
    LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION: true
});
```